# Microsoft Surface Pro 3 prevent sleeping with attached keyboard closed?

Tags: windows-8, sleep, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Microsoft Surface Pro 3, keyboard attached, placed in Surface 3 docking station.

When the keyboard is unfolded (open) the SP3 operates just fine while docked.  When the keyboard is closed (flush with screen) then the SP3 falls asleep even when docked.

Current power settings are set to "Do nothing" when plugged in and the lid is closed.

I don't want to have the keyboard open when the SP3 is docked, and I don't want to remove the keyboard when the SP3 is docked.

I am using the "second monitor only" setting when docked to use a 2560x1440 display via Display Port.